# IN clause returning only 1 row on PreparedStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm trying to optmize a query executed on a Java program at work.
We have to generate a huge ammount of data to test a program and it is taking 2~3 hours for the query to be executed.
Today, the program create a "SELECT" line for each data that we have previously stored on an ArrayList.
I'm trying to create a query with an IN clause with 1000 parameters inside of it.
I have already searched for some other examples here, but the error that I'm getting now is different from everything that I have found until now.
The query string was created perfectly, with 1000 "?" and I have set 1000 parameters with a "for", as you can see on the code.
But when I execute the query, my ResultSet object return with only 1 row, instead of the 1000 rows that I have on my database.
The code here is an adaptation from the code that I have at work, I can't post the original because of confidential reasons.
At work is an Oracle environment and at my home is a MySQL environment.

Hope that I explained in a way that someone can help me!
Thanks in advance!

```
public ArrayList<String> getDadosIn(ArrayList<String> lista)
{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList< String > listaDados = new ArrayList< String >();

    Connection conn = ConnectionUtil.getDBConnection();

    try
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat( "00" );

        System.out.println( "Begin query: " +
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) ) + "/" + // Dia
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1 )    + "/" + // Mês
                            calendar.get( Calendar.YEAR )                                + "-" + // Ano
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) )  + ":" + // Hora
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) )       + ":" + // Minuto
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.SECOND ) ) );            // Segundo

        query.append( "SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE IN (" );

        int i = 1;
        int countAux = 0;
        int countElements = 0;

        for ( int k = 0; k < lista.size(); k++ )
        {
            query.append( "?," );

            countAux++;
            countElements++;

            if(countAux >= 1000)
            {
                query.deleteCharAt( query.length() - 1 );
                query.append( ")" );
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(String.valueOf( query ) );

                for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
                {
                    ps.setInt( i++, Integer.parseInt(lista.get(countElements - 1)) );
                }

                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    listaDados.add( rs.getString("id_cliente") );
                }

                ps.close();

                query.delete( 0, query.length() );
                query.append( "SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE IN (" );

                i = 1;
                countAux = 0;

                System.out.println( "Registros selecionados: " + countElements + " - lista.size = " + listaDados.size());
            }
        }

        // verifica se ainda há registros para selecionar, uma vez que os selects acima eram executados a cada N vezes
        if(countAux > 0)
        {
            i = 1;

            query.deleteCharAt( query.length() - 1 );
            query.append( ")" );

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(String.valueOf( query ) );

            for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
            {
                ps.setInt( i++, Integer.parseInt(lista.get(countElements - 1)) );
            }

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                listaDados.add( rs.getString("id_cliente") );
            }
            ps.close();
        }

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        System.out.println( "End query: " +
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) ) + "/" + // Dia
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.MONTH ) + 1 )    + "/" + // Mês
                            calendar.get( Calendar.YEAR )                                + "-" + // Ano
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) )  + ":" + // Hora
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) )       + ":" + // Minuto
                            numberFormat.format( calendar.get( Calendar.SECOND ) ) );            // Segundo

        ps.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaDados;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things :

- In the for loop with Integer.parseInt(), the counter for lista.get(countElements - 1) needs to change to j :

  ```
      for ( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
      {
          ps.setInt( i++, Integer.parseInt(lista.get(countElements - 1)) );
      }
  ```

Change to

```
                for ( int j = 0; j < lista.size(); j++ )
                {
                    ps.setInt( i++, Integer.parseInt(lista.get( j )) );
                }
```

- For all your for loops, use the lista.size() as the upper limit to avoid IndexOutOfBounds exceptions.

  ```
              for ( int j = 0; j < lista.size(); j++ )
              {
                  ps.setInt( i++, Integer.parseInt(lista.get( j )) );
              }
  ```

Comment: I can't do that, because I'm getting the itens each 1000 times.If I use the j, it would take the itens from 0 to the end of the list, and what I want is to set a list of parameters every time the counter (countElements) reach 1000.
All the code is inside a loop that read the entire list:

for ( int k = 0; k < lista.size(); k++ )
{

}

Comment: You need to use j, in order to iterate thru your lista() ids...Using counterElements-1, you ALWAYS get the same id so your SQL ends up as WHERE ID_CLIENTE IN ( 1000, 1000, 1000, ... ).  That's why you ONLY get 1 record.

Comment: My God, how couldn't I see it? I was looking for some more complex reasons and it was right in front of me.
It's working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: feel free to check the answer for me  :-)